# In ACTION_MOVE MotionEvents, are pointers guaranteed to be indexed from low to high id?

Tags: android, motionevent

I am logging touch-based interactions to a database, and cannot afford to record all pointers.  Therefore, as I process the pointers (and historical pointers) contained in the MotionEvent, I simply ignore pointers after a certain index.  However, pointers with the lowest ids are the most relavent to me.  Is it safe to assume that the pointers are ordered (indexed) in order of pointer id, even if those ids are not guaranteed to start at zero?

Testing indicates that this assumption is correct, but I can't find any verification in the documentation.  Is anyone able to shed some light on this?

From the [Android MotionEvent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), how to process all pointers:

```
void printSamples(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int historySize = ev.getHistorySize();
    final int pointerCount = ev.getPointerCount();
    for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
        System.out.printf("At time %d:", ev.getHistoricalEventTime(h));
        for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
            System.out.printf("  pointer %d: (%f,%f)",
                ev.getPointerId(p), ev.getHistoricalX(p, h), ev.getHistoricalY(p, h));
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("At time %d:", ev.getEventTime());
    for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
        System.out.printf("  pointer %d: (%f,%f)",
            ev.getPointerId(p), ev.getX(p), ev.getY(p));
    }
 }
```

My code changes the line

```
final int pointerCount = ev.getPointerCount();
```

to

```
final int pointerCount = Math.min(ev.getPointerCount(), MAX_POINTER_COUNT);
```

which effectively gets only the first MAX_POINTER_COUNT pointers within each pointer loop.  Can I rely on those pointers having the lowest pointer ids?

Comment: Further testing seems to verify that pointers are indexed in order of ID (low to high), **but** new pointers are given the lowest unused pointer ID.  It would therefore be incorrect to assume that tracking the pointers with the lowest IDs will also be tracking the _oldest_ pointers.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the order of pointers is the order of touch on the screen, so the first pointer is the first touch and like the 3rd finger touch simultaneously is the pointer 3.

So if you want to limit to only 2 or 3 finger gestures, you can set your Max pointer to 2 or 3.

Comment: This seems to be true initially. However, when pointers are added/removed, new pointers are assigned the lowest unused pointer ID.  If a pointer has been removed, a new pointer could replace it later.